# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run android espresso tests

Tags: android, android-espresso

I've added the dependencies and it always crash with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideFailureHanderFactory`

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
}
```

The same problem happens with Espresso 3.0.1. Stacktrace:

```
Testing started at 6:24 PM ...

04/09 18:24:17: Launching CoordinatorActivityT...
$ adb push /Users/plentz/Projects/example/android/main/build/outputs/apk/debug/main-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/foo.example
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/foo.example
Success


$ adb push /Users/plentz/Projects/example/android/main/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/main-debug-androidTest.apk /data/local/tmp/foo.example.test
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/foo.example.test"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/foo.example.test
Success


Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'foo.example.ui.activity.CoordinatorActivityTest' foo.example.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.test.espresso.base.BaseLayerModule_ProvideFailureHanderFactory
at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.initialize(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:66)
at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.<init>(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:54)
at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.<init>(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:40)
at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent$Builder.build(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:123)
at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.create(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:62)
at android.support.test.espresso.GraphHolder.baseLayer(GraphHolder.java:42)
at android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.<clinit>(Espresso.java:51)
at foo.example.ui.activity.CoordinatorActivityTest.coordinatorActivityTest(CoordinatorActivityTest.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)

Tests ran to completion.
```

Comment: Are you using Proguard?

Comment: Yes. And I have `testProguardFile '../proguard/proguard.test'`